# Can I use google analytics to track usability in adobe air desktop apps?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, google-analytics

I am trying to use gaforflash to track usability on a desktop adobe air app. No luck... Is this even possible? I keep finding blogs where they say it is possible and other where they say it's not... In the google analytics for flash site they have the following comment.

Note: Currently, Flash tracking is available for any Flash content embedded in a web page. Tracking of data sent from Adobe Air, Shockwave, or via the Flash IDE (e.g. using Test Movie) is not supported at this time.

A bit lost here. Much appreciated if you could give me some advise.

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up doing a tiny bit of reverse engineering on the Javascript and Java SDKs to build a custom AS3 SDK that works for a mobile app I am developing right now. You might want to look into doing the same. That library hasn't been updated in 4+ years now. I believe the Analytics API has changed several times in that time period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use own events to grab analytics. But it not in automode. You should create many handlers. It looks like:

```
protected function init()
{
    // init tracker
    tracker = new GATracker(stage, account, "AS3", false);

    //add handlers
    videoPlayer.addEventListener(MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE, onPlayerStateChangeHandler);
}
..


protected function onPlayerStateChangeHandler(event:MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent):void 
{
    if (event.state == MediaPlayerState.BUFFERING) 
    {
        if (tracker) tracker.trackEvent("Video", "BUFFERING",  'some title');
    }       

    if (event.state == MediaPlayerState.PLAYING) 
    {
        if (tracker) tracker.trackEvent("Video", "PLAYING",  'some title');
    }
}
```